# placement of right side div and side-by-side design

Tags: html, css, layout

I'd be grateful if anyone could help me out on this one as I just cant get it to work.

Here's the code I'm struggling with: http://jsfiddle.net/sp91c3nk/

Basically, I want the right-sided navigation bar to be on the same level as the gray main content area(side-by-side). Right now it(the gray main content area) auto expands and fills up 100 %, even if I try something like margin-right: -100px. It should obly fill the space up until the nav div.

The thing is that the main div needs to be scrollable as I need to fill it with a lot of content for a little collab project between me and a few friends. Therefore it needs to be set to overflow: auto; to make sure it works nicely.
Is there any way to whip that navigation div into place? Note that I need the main content area to take up the remaining space not filed by the nav div.

Btw, the height is fixed at the moment until I get the navigation div into place. If you guys could also point out to me how I can make the both "expand" as needed in the future that would be fantastic. My google fu skills are not strong enough it seems.

Html

```
    <div id="main">
    text goes here
    </div>


    <div id="navigation">
        <br>
        <ul>
            <li> item </li>
            <li> item </li>
        </ul>

    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Css
    #wrapper
    {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    }

```
#main 
{

height: 400px;
float: left;
background-color: gray;
border: 1px solid black;
overflow: auto;
width: 100%;

}

#navigation
{
float: right;
width: 150px;
height: 400px;
background-color: yellow;
overflow: auto;

}
```

Edit: sorry. Cant seem to get the code sections right on mobile! Will edit in 15 hours

Comment: After reading Vapin's solution I am starting to have doubts what effect you want to achieve. Do you want the #navigation to scroll with your #main-div or do you want navigation to remain visible on the page at all times?

Comment: I want the navigation to remain visible at all times. Will try your solution in just a few minutes!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a calc function for the width.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sp91c3nk/4/)**

```
#main 
{
height: 400px;
float: left;
background-color: gray;
border: 1px solid black;
overflow: auto;
width: calc(100% - 152px);
}
```

Keep in mind that the -152 comes from the sum of the width paddings and borders of the #navigation.
Also keep in mind that the calc function has a [less that desirable cross-browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc).

Another solution requires changing the html. Give a shout if you want to use that and I ll make an example.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it when I get off work. Could you also give me the solution that means changing the HTML? The more I learn the merrier :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution of your problem

```css
.wrapper{
    position:relative; 
    background:white; 
    height:100%; 
    min-height:300px;
    //if the height of the box increases other div increase there size automatically. 
}
.navigation{
    width:200px; 
    background:red; 
    position:absolute; 
    right:0px; 
    height:100%; 
    overflow: auto;
}
.main{height:100%; 
    width:calc(100% - 200px); 
    background:yellow; 
    position:absolute; 
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

 <div class="navigation">navigation</div>
 
 <div class="main">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
</div>
```

you have to make few changes in your CSS just to Fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I started a new answer because my first answer does not keep the navigation in view, which you seem to want. The new answer is very simular to the one of Vipin.

**Absolute positioning**

In this technique we use absolute positioning. That means that you can place items based on distances from the edges of the parent container using the properties left, right, top, bottom. The parent container is not allowed to have position: static, that's why #wrapper has position: relative.

**#navigation**

We positioned the navigation absolute. We use the top: 0; and right: 0; to put it in the top right of the container. I also recommend setting bottom: 0; so the browser calculates the height based on the parent container. It has overflow: auto; applied in case the  navigation list ends up being too long to fit normally.

**#main**

I positioned #main simular to #navigation, except with different values for absolute positioning. I used right: 150px; (= the width of #navigation) so the #navigation will not overlap this #main.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dzqy6myb/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="main">
        <div>text goes here</div>
    </div>
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li> item </li>
            <li> item </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper{
    position: relative; /*allows absolute positioned children*/
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#main {
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
right: 150px;
height: 400px;
background-color: gray;
overflow: auto;
}

#main div{
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;   
}
#navigation{
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
/*float: right;*/
width: 150px;/*you can replace this by bottom: 0; if you want to use the height of the wrapper*/
height: 400px;
background-color: yellow;
overflow: auto;
}
```

Once again, just comment if you have further questions.

Comment: Man, this solution is fantastic. Thank you so much!